# How to Get Value from EditText to List View

Tags: android, listview

i have this code in my app which is a small unit converter

```
        setContentView(R.layout.area_acre);  

    final    EditText editAcre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editAcre);        
    final    EditText editHectar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editHectar);        
    final    EditText editSquareinch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editSquareinch);
    final    EditText editSquarekm = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editSquarekm);
    final    EditText editSquaremeter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editSquaremeter);
    final    EditText editSquaremile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editSquaremile);
    final    EditText editSquareyard = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editSquareyard);
```

and here is my button

```
    Button buttonConvert = (Button) findViewById (R.id.buttonConvertAcre);
    buttonConvert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
```

here are the vlues

```
            @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                double acre = Double.valueOf (editAcre.getText().toString());
                double hectar = acre * 0.404686;
                double squareinch = acre * 6.273e+6;
                double squarekm = acre * 0.00404686;
                double squaremeter = acre * 4046.86;
                double squaremile = acre * 0.0015625;
                double squareyard = acre * 4840;

                editHectar.setText (String.valueOf(hectar));
                editSquareinch.setText (String.valueOf(squareinch));
                editSquarekm.setText (String.valueOf(squarekm));                    
                editSquaremeter.setText (String.valueOf(squaremeter));
                editSquaremile.setText (String.valueOf(squaremile));                    
                editSquareyard.setText (String.valueOf(squareyard));    

            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                editHectar.setText ("");
            }
```

what i want to do **is to get the value from the EditText to to the list view**
i already made a string array and i called it area.
i made a listadapter and here is the code

```
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Area)));
```

and its not a custom list.
and here is my xml codes:
the button:

```
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonConvertAcre"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:minHeight="40dp"
        android:text="@string/Button" />
```

and the edittext:

```
            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textAcre"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/Acre"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="@dimen/main_text_size" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editAcre"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/layout_marginLeft"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:hint="@string/IYN"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/red_set"
            android:textSize="@dimen/hint_text_size" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

and here is the list:

```
        <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        </ListView>
```

and i have been get the result with this code:

```
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editHectar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/layout_marginLeft"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:editable="false"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textSize="@dimen/hint_text_size" />
```

and if its possible i don't want to use the button to convert i would like to have some kind of automatic converting, like i insert the number and its automatically get the value without pressing on the button.

tanks a lot in advance.

this is what i made after all and **its still dont** giving me any result!!

```
public class Area_Acre extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.area_acre);

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources()
            .getStringArray(R.array.Area)));
}
String[] stringarray = new String[7];

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Button buttonConvert = (Button) findViewById (R.id.buttonConvertAcre);
    buttonConvert.setOnClickListener(this);
    switch(v.getId()) {
    case R.id.buttonConvertAcre:
        EditText editAcre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editAcre);     
        double acre = Double.valueOf (editAcre.getText().toString());
        double hectar = acre * 0.404686;
        double squareinch = acre * 6.273e+6;
        double squarekm = acre * 0.00404686;
        double squaremeter = acre * 4046.86;
        double squaremile = acre * 0.0015625;
        double squareyard = acre * 4840;

        stringarray[0] = acre + "";
        stringarray[1] = hectar+ "";
        stringarray[2] = squareinch+ "";
        stringarray[3] = squarekm+ "";
        stringarray[4] = squaremeter+ "";
        stringarray[5] = squaremile+ "";
        stringarray[6] = squareyard+ "";
        break;}
}
```

}
can some one tell me how to fix it with some code and explanation ... i am trying to learn ... thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Where is your listview? I recomend that you define an array as a global variable then when the button is clicked assign each double value to that array. then use that array to populate the listView like this

global variable `double[] doublearray = new double[6]`

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId){
             case: R.id.buttonConvertAcre:

            double acre = Double.valueOf (editAcre.getText().toString());
            double hectar = acre * 0.404686;
            double squareinch = acre * 6.273e+6;
            double squarekm = acre * 0.00404686;
            double squaremeter = acre * 4046.86;
            double squaremile = acre * 0.0015625;
            double squareyard = acre * 4840;

            doublearray[0] = acre + ""; 
            doublearray[1] = hectar;
            //do this for every value
             break;
}
```

then set adapter to this

```
 setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, doublearray)
```

(if double array doesnt work and it wants a string array change doublearray to a string array by doing what I said above in the comment)

EDIT:

Change `double[] doublearray = new double[6]` to `String[] stringarray = new String[6];`

then do `doublearray[0] = acre + "";`

check onclick I changed it.

and you are using the onclick listener wrong, change `buttonConvert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {`

to `buttonConvert.setOnClickListener(this);`

and implement onclicklistener

Comment: when i press on the button to convert nothing is happening... and how can i change the double array to string array? can you write a simple code for that please

Comment: i did what you said and its still nothing happening ... i edited my post and post the new class check it please if i did it right or wrong!! thanks

Comment: You didnnt set up on onclicklistner properly, look at this http://anujarosha.wordpress.com/2011/11/13/how-to-implements-onclicklistener-for-a-view-item-in-android/

Comment: i understood that nice example .. but i am not so professional with android programing ... and my case is edittext and list view but thanks any way.